# Display the result of the search bar in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Good day to all I have trouble in codeigniter it suppose to display the data (the first name and the student id of the student) in my oracle database depending on what I type in the search box. for example i the the name of student to the search box when i click the submit button it will display the data of that student. i try to search some code and use it but it displayed error  404 page not found. here is the code

This is for the view mysearch.php

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('search/search_keyword');?>" method = "post">
    <input type="text" name = "keyword" />
    <input type="submit" value = "Search" />
</form>
```

This is for the controller search.php

```
Class Search Extends CI_Controller
{
    function __Construct()
    {        
        parent::__Construct();

        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('mymodel');
    }

    function search_keyword()
    {
        $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');
        $data['results'] = $this->mymodel->search($keyword);

        $this->load->view('result_view', $data);
    }
}
```

This is for the Model mymodel.php

```
Class Mymodel Extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function search($keyword)
    {

        $this->db->like('name',$keyword);
        $query = $this->db->get('tablename');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

This is for the view result_view.php

```
<table>
<?php
    foreach ($results as $row) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row->FIRST_NAME?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->STUDENT_ID?></td>
</tr>
<?php   
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: I think you inverted opening and closing php tags around ''foreach($results as $row){'' in the last piece of code

Comment: I see no obvious error in the code, the 404 makes me rather think of a file name issue, routing or URL rewrite

Comment: i try <?php
foreach($results as $row){
?> but the error still the same.

Comment: can you show us what the value of the action attribute in the form is?

Comment: Yes I know, that it not the cause of the 404 error. Did you check the target of the form was correct ? Is the base_url correctly set in your config.php ?

Comment: my setting in my base url is this $config['base_url'] = ''; aurel.g

Comment: anurupr what action attribute? do you mean <form action="<?php echo site_url('search/search_keyword');?>" method = "post">

Comment: I fix it, i force codeigniter to access my mysearch.php in the view folder. public function index()
 {
  $this->load->view('mysearch');
 }

Comment: thanks for anurupr and aurel.g how spend time and share thier knowledge in this post. thank you very much, and more powers to you all.